# Perform a remote Heap dump programmatically

Tags: jmx, visualvm

How does JVisualVM perform a remote Heap dump?

I'd like to do the same programmatically. Is there a JMX API I can use?
Note I don't want to download the heap dump. Just perform it and save it to a location on the remote server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.html#dumpHeap(java.lang.String, boolean). This mbean is always registered in the platform MBeanServer on hotspot JVMs.

Comment: Example https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/programmatically_dumping_heap_from_java